# Updating SharedObject Data Value in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I want to update the value of  _third.data["#ID"] in this code. What i want to do it to add something with  _third.data["#ID"] when storing it in this.ID

What i want to do is:

```
            this.ID = "myvalue" + _third.data["#ID"];
```

but in output i get myvalueundefined but if i remove "myvalue" from code thn it works fine  and gives me the correct value please help me my knowledge of actionscript isn't that much i just learned some of it from internet.

Here is the coding:

```
    public function main(_first:String, _second:Array, _third:SharedObject):Object{
            this.ID = _third.data["#ID"];
        };
```

What i want to do is:

```
    public function main(_first:String, _second:Array, _third:SharedObject):Object{
            this.ID = "myvalue" + _third.data["#ID"];
        };
```

Comment: What's the type of ID?

Comment: It's defined at top of the as file         var ID:String = null;

Answer (score 1):

Using your code, I created the below test case. It's doing the same as your code, and is outputting the expected values.

```
package kazo 
{
    import flash.net.SharedObject;
    /**
     * ...
     * @author KM
     */
    public class TestCases 
    {

        private var ID      :String = null;

        public function TestCases() { }

        /**
         * Start the test case
         */
        public function start():void {
            trace('Starting test case');

            var SO:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal('TestCases');

            if (!SO.data["#ID"]) {
                trace('SO data not found, creating');
                SO.data["#ID"] = '123';
                SO.flush();
            }

            getID(SO);

        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param   _SO
         */
        public function getID(_SO:SharedObject):void {
            this.ID = "myvalue" + _SO.data["#ID"];
            // trace = myvalue123
            trace(this.ID);
        }

    }

}
```

trace:

```
(fcsh)Build succeeded
Done(0)
[Starting debug session with FDB]
Starting test case
myvalue123
```

If you're still having problems, I'd suggest trying to call toString() on the value you're pulling, so:

```
this.ID = "myvalue" + _SO.data["#ID"].toString();
```

Should that still not work, store it in two separate String variables and then combined them.

Comment: Thanks for you detailed response KM but its still not working i even tried .toString(); method as you mentioned and also tried to store it in 2 different string variables and combine them but still shows null or undefined after the word myvalue. I also tested 2 variables by inserting value in them by myself instead of  _SO.data["#ID"] and that way it works fine so the problem exist in _SO.data["#ID"]. Dont u think there should be a way to simpley grab and update the value of _SO.data["#ID"].

Comment: That's the thing, if I use the above code which I posted, it works fine. It sounds like you're trying to do more than you described and something else is going wrong. You can access any part of a sharedobject's data by calling data['variable'] and it will either get, or set it. Can you test my above code, in a brand new document? Does it work? If it doesn't, are you sure you have Flash Local storage enabled?

Comment: i uploaded the whole code of that actionscript file can you please check it at http://codeviewer.org/view/code:41cb and look at this.UID = _arg3.data["#UID"]; at 59-60 line. This where i want to add value into _arg3.data["#UID"];

Comment: Firstly, this looks like decompiled code. Secondly you have no call to the Main function in this class. Thirdly, you override UID on line 242 to be a different value. The code that I provided above, does work. If you're trying to take somebody elses code, for a SharedObject that was saved on a different domain, you will not have access to that data, which would explain why you're getting undefined. There is no way around this.